# Improving listening skills

Tags: communication

I have found over time that I am very bad at listening. However, at work we have tonnes of meetings, and most of what we do is verbal communication. At meetings, I tend to space out a lot. I am trying to figure out how to prevent that and improve my listening skills.

To improve my listening skills, I am thinking of starting to write notes after the meeting, instead of during meeting or any meetups I attend. This will kind of force me to pay attention, and hopefully my listening will improve over time. 
What strategies have you used to improve your listening skills?

Comment: Have you tried taking notes during the meeting?  You might want to take notes during the meeting and then sending out a summary email after the meeting.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere, thanks for pointing that out.. I havent heard of that before.. is there a specific class or workshop you had in mind? I will google to find out whats available nearby and online. I am in the bay area. Money is not too much of a concern..I think this is a big deficit of mine.. so have to improve this..

Comment: @JasonJ, Thank for the suggestion..I used to take notes before, but I found that I was taking copious notes without comprehension on my laptop.. so I thought I should rather listen and retain. Nonetheless sometimes the topics we discuss become very complicated and if I space out for a little bit, I am done..even for very senior engineers with 10s of years of experience, it gets hard. So I was thinking if I listen and force myself to write down after the meeting.. I would get better at retention.. Do you have any advice or reference for good note-taking?

Comment: I agree with @JoeStrazzere; there is a wealth of good material on communication, and you can find it fairly easily if you look.  One course that really stands out for me is the [Success Through Communication Course](http://www.scientology-sanfrancisco.org/beginning-services/success-through-communication-course.html), developed by L. Ron Hubbard.  (It stands out because it is not just *theory* but has extremely workable exercises with precise passing standards that you work through with a course partner.)  I am now a professional sysadmin consultant and trainer, if that counts for anything.

Comment: @alpha_989 Take notes with pen and paper; it is better for paying attention. If you want to archive the notes for later, then you can transfer them to the laptop after the meeting.

Comment: Thanks all.. I am starting to take notes with my pen and paper from today. Will try that out for a month or so.., and see whether that helps. Will be transferring notes to my laptop.. 

If I need to improve further.. I will check out the course by Hubbard suggested by Wildcard.. and others.. 

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would actually think that taking notes during the meeting would force you to listen to the meetings and write down the most important part.

Additionally, if you try and participate during these meetings, even just by making small comments or suggestions, this would help you to absorb the content as well.

Comment: Thanks. I was commenting before as well. That definitely helps.. I have starting making small notes, and will leave my laptop on my desk as much as possible, to reduce my tendency to check my laptop.. 

I dont like taking physical notes, because its hard to keep track of them. But I will make more detailed notes from my notepad onto my laptop once I get back to my desk.